# Java: Read, edit and create a text file

Tags: java, file, function, text

I have a Java program that creates `Swords`. Now, I want to store the damagevalue and name of these `Swords` in a text file, and be able to read these values later. What is the best way to do that?

I have two classes:
`Sword.java` and `NewSword.java`, where `NewSword.java` is the function to create a new sword (o.O). Here's the code:

```
Sword.java:

package game;

public class Sword {
    public static int numberOfSwords=0;

    public static void main(String [] args){
        functions.NewSword.newSword("Wooden Sword", 2);
        System.out.println(numberOfSwords);
    }
}
```

and

```
NewSword.java:

package functions;

public class NewSword {
        public static void newSword(String nameSword, int damageSword){
            game.Sword.numberOfSwords++;
        }
}
```

So:
I wish to be able to, in the function `newSword(String nameSword, int damageSword)`, put the `nameSword` and the `damageSword` in a text file, and be able to read that... So that I can later do like: "He has a wooden sword, what's the damage?"... I want to put it in a text file, because I want to know how that works, and practice with it. Also, I think it makes it easier if I want to add features to swords, and can put those in text files as well... Hope you can help me!

EDIT: I put the function in another package, that's why it's `functions.NewSword.newSword("Wooden Sword", 2);`, just for the heck of it :D But also to be a bit organized...

Comment: I'd recommend getting familiar with object oriented programming first. That'll make Java much easier to use.

Comment: Well, I'm practicing right now ^ ^. I don't know if what I ask is too hard for a noob like me, but I'd like to hear suggestions for what I can do better, or other ways to achieve the same thing...

Comment: You could create the class Sword, with each instance of the class representing an individual sword with their own names and damages.

Comment: But then I'll have to type all the things over and over... That won't be very handy for say a hundred swords ^ ^. I'd like to do that with a function...

Comment: No you won't, you just need to create a constructor that you can invoke as many times as you want.

Comment: How can I do that? Because when you use those variables in a constructor, it would change all the time, or not? Because I thought, when you use damageSword for the wooden sword, it will get 2, and when you reuse it, it will get another value, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read throught this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm
It explains everything in from creating a file to reading it and will sure help you out.

However regard kviiris commend about learning something about object oriented programming.
Heres the basic approach for your swords:

You write a class for your sword that contains all the information you need for a given sword.

```
public class Sword {
 private String name;
 private int damage;

 // this is the constructor to create new swords
 public Sword(String name, int damage){
  this.name = name;
  this.damage = damage;
 }
}
```

Now you can access this from your main class and use it to create as many swords as you want simply with

```
Sword s = new Sword("wooden sword", 2);
Sword s2 = new Sword("iron sword", 20);
```

Note: you used the same class (Sword) but this are still 2 completely separate swords.
Thats the main use of object oriented programming.

Comment: So now s is a variable from the king `Sword`, am I right? Which holds the value of `"wooden sword", 2`... And the `this.name`, does that mean that `s` will get the name of the String name? That you mean `s` with `this`?

Comment: The second half of his question is about serialization.  Use something like xml or json, or yaml as the output format, and just hand their serialization methods a filestream once you've figured out how to output your swords to a string.  For example add a toJSON() function to your sword... or something equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

This will compile.

### Game.java

```
package game;

import functions.Sword;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Game {

    List<Sword> swords = new ArrayList<Sword>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Game game = new Game();

        game.play();

    }

    public void play() {

        swords.add(new Sword("Wooden sword", 2));
        swords.add(new Sword("Silver sword", 4));

        System.out.println(swords.size());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(swords));

    }

}
```

### Sword.java

```
package functions;

public class Sword {

    private final String name;
    private final int damage;

    public Sword(String name, int damage) {
        this.name = name;
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getDamage() {
        return damage;
    }
}
```